# Building apache hadoop 2.6.0 throwing maven error

Tags: maven, hadoop

When i try to build hadoop 2.6.0 with command

```
mvn package -Pdist,native,docs -DskipTests -Dtar
```

I see the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-annotations: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/InterfaceStability.java:27: error: unexpected end tag: </ul>
[ERROR] * </ul>
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/target' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-annotations: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive: 
Exit code: 1 - /home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/InterfaceStability.java:27: error: unexpected end tag: </ul>
 * </ul>
```

If i go to the source and remove that tag then the build proceed a little further and then again some other tag issue. This is my first ever source compilation. Kindly suggest.

Comment: i found that adding -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true with the command resolved the issue.

Comment: Simple try mvn package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar to build hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Raghuveer already figured it out, a workaround shown below is suggested on their JIRA link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11449

```
mvn clean package -Pdist -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -fail-at-end -Pnative
```

FYI, this issue doesn't happen with hadoop-2.7.0.